# connection textfield and html table with database

Tags: php, javascript, jquery, mysql

dear all..i have a textfield

```
<tr>
<td>
<td><input type="text" id="model_name"></td>
</td>
</tr>
```

and a cell

```
<tr>
<td><div id="value">//i want data show here after fill textfield</div>
</td>
</tr>
```

beside that, i've a table "settingdata" in database it consist of 2 field:itemdata and remark..
itemdata's value are "UD" and remark's value are "FM=87.5-108.0MHZ"...

what must i do if i want after type model name "car01UD" at textfield inside

```
<div id="value"></div>
```

can show "FM=87.5-108.0mhz"...

Comment: what is 0103 number in the "0103UD"?

Comment: @all: i change my sample for fill textfield

Comment: my question also change then what is "car01"? Is it hardcoded string or what?

Comment: that's just a text which i want to input

Answer (score 1, accepted):

if you want "0103" + value of itemdata then do following

```
<input type="text" id="mod" value="0103<?PHP echo $itemdata ?>">
```

Comment: i've been change 0103 into car01UD..that's a data for input inside textfield...i need at 2 character can control the cell to take FM=... from database

Answer (score 0):

Looks like you are trying to do basic Ajax functionality. Consider reading some [Ajax tutorials](http://docs.jquery.com/Tutorials:Getting_Started_with_jQuery#Rate_me:_Using_Ajax) to get an idea how to do this.